# How to control windows Sound recorder using java script

Tags: javascript, audio-recording

I am making some thing that requires that I have to control windows sound recorder like starting recording and stopping recording and saving the recorded sound. how to control that. One thing more I don't want to see the recorder window. I will be grateful to who give the answer..

Comment: I am making an extension of Firefox that uses only javascript. I am able to open sound recorder but not able to start/stop recording and the window is displaying. this is the main problem

Answer (score 1):

If you intend to make this through a browser, you can't. JavaScript doesn't have the permission to do any of those actions, since it would be a big security hole. You might be able to access the recorder through an embedded object, but I have never tried this, so I don't know for sure.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on what Machine said, why not try Flash, I'm sure that has the ability to use recorder.

Answer (score 0):

I am making an extension of Firefox that uses only javascript. I am able to open sound recorder but not able to start/stop recording and the window is displaying. this is the main problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this: http://www.iol.ie/~locka/mozilla/plugin.htm